# How to import a dynamic object in nodejs

Tags: node.js, dynamic, module, export

First, sorry for my bad English. I have one problem with my code. I have a dynamic object in one javacript file (the values in keys are changing per second). I want to use this object to the other file and so I'm using export and require.
soure.js

```
module.exports = {name: name, age: age}
```

Note that name and age are changing per second randomly

target.js

```
let person = require('./soure.js')
console.log(person)
```

It will return an emty object like {}, not like from what I've expected. So my question is: How can I use the source's object in target file?

Thank all

Answer (score 0):

You can write the source file as a function:

```
export const nameAgeObject = (name, age) => ({
  name: name,
  age: age
});
```

And then when you are importing the function you can declare the values as variables.

```
import {nameAgeObject} from './soure.js' //(or require)
```

And then use it as:

```
const myNameAgeObject = nameAgeObject("George",21);
```